# How to identify unbound variables for auto-including of modules using Template Haskell?

Tags: templates, haskell

Is it possible to use Template Haskell to pre-analyze a code, searching for undefined symbols and including them, if they are defined elsewhere? I.E, simulating Eclipse's auto-include for Java programs (except not actually altering the source)?

Comment: How would you deal with functions with multiple definitions, like `(<>)` (in Data.Monoid and Data.Semigroup), or `sortBy` (in at least Data.List and Data.Vector.Algorithms), or `head` (which is implemented by every sequential container I can think of)?

Comment: Last I looked, Template Haskell could not add imports.  This would have to be a more complete source to source transformation.  Anyone please correct me if I missed a TH feature.

Comment: @argiopeweb I should've made it clear, it is supposed to add only my own functions from a specific folder (which will obviously only contain unique names).

Comment: @Viclib Ah, much more clear, thank you. This isn't currently a feature, but has been pushed for before. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently a feature of GHC, though the suggestion and multiple use cases have been proposed [in the GHC Trac](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1475).

It could be interesting to determine how much work it would take to get this into the next version of GHC.

Comment: Interesting, but I guess "opened 6 years ago" don't give much hope.

Comment: The fact that it hasn't been closed probably implies that a patch would be accepted, if anyone were to put the time into making one.

Comment: @arglopeweb is labor force an actual problem for Haskell right now?

Comment: @Viclib Development on GHC is almost entirely community led. There are over 300 open feature requests, and only so many people who are interested, capable, and willing to take ownership of any given feature. It's less that the compiler lacks a labor force, and more that nobody who is interested in TH imports and knows anything about the compiler has stepped up to add the feature.